# Regarding the quote (') in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, chicken-scheme

My understanding is that the single quote `'` in Scheme is used to tell Scheme that what follows is a symbol and not a variable. Hence, it should not be evaluated.
Based on this understanding, I don't get why Chicken prints `1.0` when I enter `'3/3` at the REPL.

```
CHICKEN
(c) 2008-2016, The CHICKEN Team
(c) 2000-2007, Felix L. Winkelmann
Version 4.11.0
linux-unix-gnu-x86-64 [ 64bit manyargs dload ptables ]
compiled 2016-08-23 on buildvm-13.phx2.fedoraproject.org

#;1> '3/3
1.0
```

I expected it to print `3/3`. Why does this get evaluated instead of a quote being present?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote is a syntax which expands to a `quote` expression. That is to say, `'X` means `(quote X)`, whatever `X` is. `quote` is an operator whose value is the argument syntax itself. For instance, the value of `(quote (+ 2 2))` is the list `(+ 2 2)` itself, rather than the value `4`. Likewise, `(quote a)` yields the symbol `a` rather than the value of the expression `a`.

Like other Lisp dialects, Scheme programs are written in a data notation. Every element of the source code of a Scheme program corresponds to an identifiable data structure which a Scheme program could manipulate. `quote` is a way of gaining access to a piece of the program's body as a literal object, passing that object into the program's space of run-time values.

`3/3` is a token which denotes a number. That number is `1.0`. Some objects have more than one "spelling". Sometimes you use one spelling when entering the object into the Lisp system, and when it is printed, a different spelling is used.

The `3/3` evaluation is not the usual expression evaluation, but something which occurs when the token is scanned and converted to an object.

Try entering `3/3` **without** the quote.

Analogy: your question is like:

> How come when I type `'1.0E3`, I get `1000.0`? The exponent `E3` is being evaluated in spite of the quote!

However, I would expect `3/3` and `'3/3` to produce `1` rather than `1.0`.

The reason `3/3` denotes `1.0` is that Chicken Scheme doesn't have full support for rational numbers, "out of the box". See this mailing list posting:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/chicken-users/2013-03/msg00032.html

Also see the recommendation: there is an "egg" (Chicken Scheme module) called `numbers` which provides the "full numerical tower". "Numerical tower" is a Lisp jargon for the type system of numbers. A "full tower" means having "the works": complex numbers, rationals, bignum integers, floating-point numbers in multiple precision and so on.

Comment: This response is spot on. Note that CHICKEN 5 will have the full numerical tower built in, because we found out that having it as an optional add-on causes some fundamental problems, and it's not very efficient.

Comment: Some Schemes (probably Chicken too) support pipes in symbol literals such as in  '|a b|  and '|3/3| which will evaluate to a symbol  a b  and a symbol 3/3. The first symbol has a name with the space and the second symbol has a name that looks like a number literal.

Comment: @sjamaan Any sort of add-on that globally changes  programming language semantics is obviously a computer science flunk job.  About pipes, if `|3/3|` prints back `3/3` without the pipes, then there is a read-print consistency problem.

Comment: Actually, the real problem is that it doesn't globally affect the semantics. This means you can have one piece of code that loads "numbers", which may generate extended numerics, while other code that doesn't use "numbers" will not accept those numerics. Regarding pipes: when a symbol requires pipes to quote it, CHICKEN will also print them back, so AFAICT there is no problem. Note that the _symbol_ `3/3` is not the same as the _number_ `3/3`.